# How to Move Data from Transactional Databases to a Master Database with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I am very new to SSIS and I need to write a package that will move data from transactional databases to a master database. We have a transactional database per plant and the schema for all of these is identical. I need to go through each table in each database and copy all the data that hasn't been marked as exported to its corresponding table in the master database. After the records are successfully copied to the master database they should be marked as exported in the transactional database.

So far I've gotten my SSIS package to where I can iterate through the plant databases and read from one of the tables. I'm currently storing the resuls from that table into a variable. I accomplished the iteration part by using an expression in the For Each Loop Container's Connection Manager that sets the Initial Catalog to the current database name in the loop.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed after that. Here's a picture of my package's current state:

[image]

I've tried creating another Execute SQL Task that takes the results from Get New Apples and copies them to the master database. However, from what I've googled so far there doesn't seem to be an easy way to accomplish this.

A different approach I've tried is to create an OLE DB Source using the same connection manager as the For Each Loop Container. When I do that I get an error saying that the Apple table is not a valid object(My query being `select * from Apple where exported = 0;`).

Any suggestions as to how I can read a result set from a variable or get the OLE DB Source to work with the aforementioned Connection Manager would be very helpful.

I'm also open to alternate methods to accomplishing this. Like I said, I'm new to SSIS and am still feeling my way around it.

Originally I tried to make this as a stored procedure but it started to grow unmanagable and ugly very quickly:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #tempapple
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   [Plant1].[dbo].[Apple] 
        WHERE  exported = 0 
        UNION 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   [Plant2].[dbo].[Apple] 
        WHERE  exported = 0) AS x; 

INSERT INTO [Master].[dbo].[Apple] 
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       description, 
       active, 
       plant 
FROM   #tempapple
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM   [Master].[dbo].[Apple]); 

UPDATE [Plant1].[dbo].[Apple] 
SET    exported = 1 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   #tempapple); 

UPDATE [Plant2].[dbo].[Apple] 
SET    exported = 1 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   #tempapple); 

DROP TABLE #tempapple;
```

Comment: If all transaction databases and master database are on the same SQL Server, you don't have to use SSIS. You can just write T-SQL/stored procedure to accomplish this.

Comment: A stored procedure was my original approach but it didn't lend itself well to getting the data from all the transactional databases. It's also not possible(that I'm aware of) to parameterize the database name in a stored procedure so my original attempt was looking very long and unmanagable. I'll update my question w/ an exceprt from my stored procedure

Comment: Bruno, the stored proc route needs a cursor. which in SSIS lingo is like a foreach

Comment: @KeithL aren't cursors the devil in terms of performance? I'm mostly a programmer so I'm basing this on things I've heard from co-workers in the past

Comment: They can be, but this is justified and will not be a problem and do exactly what you are doing above but more clean

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Should the data transfers be happening on real time or on a scheduled basis? Are you having primary keys set for all the tables or have any datetime field to be able to batch them? How many databases and tables within each are we talking about approx?

Comment: @VKarthik We're using SQL server 2014. The data transfers will need to happen at regular intervals, probably once a day. The tables in the plant databases all have primary keys. The master tables also have primary keys but they are composite(ex. Apples table in plant1 db has primary key of int Id. Apples table in master db has primary key of int Id, and int PlantNumber). There are 2 plant databases at the moment but there will be more soon. Each db has about 8 tables.

Comment: Thanks for info. The two appraoches to this problem that I have in mind are via CDC or creating a comprehensive framework in place to be able to iterate through all tables of all databases and get the data across. Will get back to you on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to settle for a mix of my two approaches. The SSIS package remains mostly the same with the logic to iterate through each plant database. Within the loop I now have several Execute SQL Tasks to import data from the various tables. The logic for the import apples task looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #tempapple 
FROM   (SELECT * 
    FROM   apple 
    WHERE  exported = 0); 

INSERT INTO [Master].[dbo].[apple] 
SELECT id, 
   NAME, 
   description, 
   active, 
   plant 
FROM   #tempapple 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   [Master].[dbo].[apple]); 

UPDATE apple 
SET    exported = 1 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
          FROM   #tempapple); 

DROP TABLE #tempapple;
```

This allows me to not have reduntant SQL since each task will be executed once per plant database.

Answer (score 1):

I've got to make a few assumptions here:

1. The variable is type 'Object'
2. the foreach loop is on an ADO.Object enumerator setting the db name to a variable
3. insert an expression before the dataflow
4. in the expression set a new variable type string to "Select * from " + [dbname] + ".[schema].[tablename]  where exported = 0"
   4a. Note that dbname comes the enumerable set in #2
5. In your dataflow, set your source to variable and use that variable in #4.

This should get your data at least loaded.

You have options, for updated the isExported column in the source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this directly so you may need to modify it slightly.

```
declare  @dbname as varchar(100) -- dbname
declare @SQL varchar(max)

declare db_cursor cursor for
[ this is where you insert your code for getting DBnames]

OPEN db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname

while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    set @SQL = "Select * into #temptable from " + @dbname + ".[dbo].[Apple] where exported = 0
INSERT INTO [Master].[dbo].[Apple] 
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       description, 
       active, 
       plant 
FROM   #tempapple
-- no where clause needed

UPDATE " + @dbname + ".[dbo].[Apple] 
SET    exported = 1 
from " + @dbname + ".[dbo].[Apple] a
join #temptable tt  on a.id=tt.id

DROP TABLE #tempapple; "

exec(@sql);
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname
END

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Comment: I did consider using dynamic syntax when I was looking at using a stored procedure but I wasn't too fond of writing sql in a string.

Comment: the trick is to make it work without the string format and then replace the variable around the SQL.